# Running codebehind function on <a> click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i tried that:

but it doesnt work

here is my code, aspx:

```
<div id='settingNev' >
<ul >
   <li><a onserverclick="show_view1" runat="server"><span>changeView1</span></a></li>
   <li><a onserverclick="show_view2" runat="server"><span>changeView2</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

code behind:

```
protected void show_view1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
}

protected void show_view2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
}
```

aspx, the views:

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        View1
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        View2
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
```

is there any other way? or can you see the problem in the code?

Tnx for the help :D

Comment: Have you tried to specify Id for your links? `<a id="show_view1_link"...>`

Comment: i added id and it worked, Tnx for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use a LinkButton with its OnClick event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Click Me"  
           OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>
```

Code behind

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         Label1.Text="You clicked the link button";
      }
```

Comment: +1 This is a good practice for WebForms to use server controls like a LinkButton instead of plain html.

Comment: i dont want to use LinkButton because of my css, but Tnx any way. problem solved all i needed was id

Comment: You can apply CSS to the generated HTML too. You can set the CssClass property, or use ClientIDMode to determine how the ID is named, etc. Glad you found a solution though.